# Are total instance storage per region and Aurora Volume separate?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

According to the AWS doc(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html) Aurora's total instance storage per region is 100,000 GB(100TB).

And It is said that the aurora cluster is automatically scaled up to 128 TiB.

If I create 4 aurora clusters in RDS and one cluster is scaled up to 128 TiB, does an error occur when scaling up the other 3 clusters?

Or is it possible to scale up all 4 clusters to 128 TiB each?(Are total instance storage per region and Aurora Volume separate?)

I would be grateful if there is any document I can refer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100TB is the **default** limit for Aurora storage per region. That means you won't be able to scale up any single instance to the maximum 128TB, in a single region, because that would be more than the default limit.

> Or is it possible to scale up all 4 clusters to 128 TiB each?(Are total instance storage per region and Aurora Volume separate?)

No, that would be 512TB of Aurora storage in a single region, which would be more than the default limit of 100TB.

If your combined storage of all Aurora instances in a single region is going to be more than 100TB, you have to fill out a quota increase request, to get the limit raised on your account.

Comment: I don't usually do this but OMG, thank you!  This fact just saved us from many days of pointless effort.